# KnockoutJS: Writable computed observable not updating

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have the following code where I am trying to use a writable computed observable to validate user input, and automatically reject invalid input.
This is just some test code where I am trying to prevent the user from deleting the comma character from the text. If the user deletes the comma character I am attempting to rebind the editor to the prior value to overwrite the most recent change.
Is this possible using a writable computed field?
The issue that I am having is that the writable computed binding fires only when I load the page (after manually setting the ValidText prop.) I can't however get it to fire when the user types into the editor.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var model = null;

    function EditModel() {

        this.Count = 2;

        var self = this;

        this.ExistingValue = ko.observable("");

        this.ValidText = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return self.ExistingValue();
            },
            write: function (text) {
                if (text.split(',').length === self.Count) {
                    self.ExistingValue(text);
                }
            },
            owner: self
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        model = new EditModel();

        model.ValidText('@(Model.Text)');

        ko.applyBindings(model);
    });

</script>

<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" class="commentEditBox" data-bind="text: ValidText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" ></div>
</div>
```

Ended up going with the custom binding idea and converted the code to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var model = null;

    ko.bindingHandlers.customEditorBinding = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            $(element).on('keydown', function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(this).text());
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var text = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            if (text.split(',').length === model.Count) {
                model.ValidText(text);
                model.PreviousText = text;
                $(element).text(text);
            }
            else {
                 model.ValidText(model.PreviousText);
                $(element).text(model.PreviousText);
            }
        }
    };

    function EditModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.Count = 2;

        self.ValidText = ko.observable("");

        self.PreviousText = null;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        model = new EditModel();

        model.ValidText('This is,a test');

        ko.applyBindings(model);
    });

</script>

<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" class="commentEditBox" data-bind="customEditorBinding:ValidText" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, confusing use of self and this apart, you've bound it to a div using text, and you're trying to get it to update when the value changes. There is no value on that html element, so that's why it's not firing.

Have a look at [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) and move your write logic into the update method of it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

Comment: I agree it's inconsistent, but it shouldn't matter. I updated it to use self for all of them, but still same issue

Comment: Fair enough, but I always look for the simplest explanations first, and inconsistencies are a good place to start! Anyway, try this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your write method, add this else clause:

```
else { self.ValidText.notifySubscribers(self.ExistingValue()); }
```

That will force the textbox to update back to the original value.

Comment: The issue is that I can't get it to fire. tried adding the else, but it never reaches that condition since it only fires initially when it's valid